# enable cookie.js in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cookies

I use jquery.cookie.js plugin for my application (within server, only html5)

the follow code works for IE9 an firefox but not for Chrome :

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

If I run Chrome with option --enable-file-cookies it's OK and my Chrome browser support cookies

My question : Is it any way to enable this option with javascript not by terminal?

Comment: Move it to the server or run it through local server, the `file:///` scheme has many other restrictions that you will run into as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chrome has problems if you test that on 'localhost'. Use 127.0.0.1 instead

Comment: All suggests that he doesn't even have a local web server

Answer (score 0):

No it is security related approach in Google Chrome. It should be a bug in Chrome if you are able to enable something the client disabled it.